# Print separate page based on data table html

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm having a trouble on how can I separate the page based on the countries column. All I want is to print the countries separately example United States should print in the first page the next country like Germany should automatically display or print on the second page and so on... and so on...Currently I only print my data table at once. How can I separate them? Can anyone give me an idea or solution how can I achieve this? Is there any expert can help me,I have an example fiddle below you can try it thank you in advance!!

> Fiddle
> [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/59Lmuexg/)

[image: Sample]

> html

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary round btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1"  onclick="printDiv();">Print</button>
<section class="users-list-wrapper">
<div class="users-list-table">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-body">
                <!-- datatable start -->
                <div class="table-responsive">

            <table  class="table" name="table" id="table">

            <thead>

            <th colspan="9">
               <div class="titles"><h3>This is Header title <br style="line-height: 20%;"><span 
               class="header2"> SubHeader title</span></h3>
                </div>  
                </th>
            <tr><th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;"> <span class="municipality">Header</span> 
            </th>
            </tr>
            <span>Hello</span> </h1>
            <tr class="heads">
                <th class="heads">No</th>
                <th width ="5%" class="heads">ID Number</th>
                <th class="heads">Name</th>
                <th width ="8%" class="heads">Country</th>
                <th class="heads">Data total</th>
               

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="report-content">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Unite States</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Unite States</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Unite States</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Unite States</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Unite States</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Unite States</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Germany</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Germany</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Germany</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Germany</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>Germany</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>China</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>China</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>China</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>
                               
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1235</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>China</td>
                    <td class="lenss"></td>                 
                </tr>   
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

> javascript

```
function printDiv() {
  let tbl = document.getElementById('table');
  let title = document.querySelector('.titles');
  let newTitle = title.cloneNode(true);
  newTitle.style.textAlign = "center";
  newTitle.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  tbl.prepend(newTitle);
  title.remove();

  var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');

  var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
   '.titles  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'font-size: 14px;' +
    '}' +

    '.municipality {' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-size: 14px;' +
    'text-align: left;' +
    
    '}' +

    '.presented  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'width:130px;' +
    'padding 5px;' +
    'font-size: 14px;' +

    '}' +


    

    '.footer  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'text-align: right;' +
    'font-size: 13px;' +
    '}' +

    '.numbers  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'text-align: left;' +
    'font-size: 13px;' +
    '}' +

 

    '.certify  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-size: 13px;' +
    'text-align: left;' +
    'font-weight: normal;' +
    'margin-top: 15px;' +

    '}' +

    '.chief  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'text-align: left;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'margin-top: 40px;' +
    'font-size: 13px;' +
    '}' +

    '.positions  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'text-align: left;' +
    'font-weight: normal;' +
    'font-size: 13px;' +
    '}' +

    '.rev  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'text-align: left;' +
    'font-weight: normal;' +
    'margin-top: 30px;' +
    'font-size: 13px;' +
    '}' +



    'table td,.heads {' +
    'border:1px solid #000000;' +
    'padding:5px;' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;'+
    'font-size: 14px;' +
    '}' +

    'tbody tr  {' +
    'counter-increment: noElm;' +
    '}' +

    '.lenss {' +
    'padding-left:80px;' +
    'font-size: 13px;' +
    '}' +

    'td:nth-of-type(1):before {' +
    'content: counter(noElm);' +
    '}' +

    'th:nth-of-type(1),td:nth-of-type(1) {' +
    'display: table-cell;' +
    '}' +

    'table  {' +
    'border-collapse: collapse;' +
    'width: 100%;' +
    '}' +

     '.cash  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight: 550;' +
    'font-size: 14px;' +
    '}' +

    '.header2  {' +
    'font-family:Calibri, san-serif;' +
    'font-weight:normal;' +
    'font-size: 14px;' +


    '</style>';
  htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
  newWin = window.open("");
  newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
```

> css

```
 @media screen {
 th:nth-of-type(1),
 td:nth-of-type(1) {
 display: none;
 }
 .noPrint {}

 .titles {
  display: none;
 }
 .footer,.municipality,.certify,.numbers,.chief,.positions,.rev {
 display: none;
 }
 }
@media print {
  .noPrint {
    display: none;
  }
  .title {}
  .footer {}
  }

@page{
    size: auto;
    margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;  
}
body  
{ 
    margin: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: @ATD do you have any idea for this?

Comment: I don't actually receive notifications that way - not sure why, I think it is because there are several users called `ATD`!  Anyway, you need to add in a class for the first `tr` that contains a new country - this should set `page-break-before: always;`  Is the table generated by code or just by tags already defined in the HTML page?

Comment: @ATD I see it's okay thanks for your response, by the way the data is dynamic random countries, should it break using page-break-before: always;  ?

Comment: OK - if it is generated by code, the class can be added at that point.  But I'll look at adding it after the table is displayed, so you can see what it is doing and check that it does what you need.

Comment: @ATD thaks for your response What should I supposed to do?

Comment: See my Answer - this is for the table if it is already loaded onto the page.  It you construct it by javascript, hopefully this will show you what you need to do.  Apart from the first country, whenever the country name changes (column 4, so cell 3), add the new class to the `tr` tag.

Comment: ps - you spelled "United States" incorrectly - unless you are making a political statement to "Unite States" somehow? ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Using your coding etc, I think you can do this to set the page breaks during printing (note that this can't be done in a snippet, so you will have to copy this into a new HTML page to test it):

**SCRIPT** - adds new class `reportpage` to the `tr` tag whenever the country name changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addReportPages() {
  let lastCountry = "";
  let table = document.getElementsByClassName("report-content")[0];
  let rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  rows.forEach(function(row){
    let thisCountry = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
    if (lastCountry == "") {
      lastCountry = thisCountry;
    } else if (thisCountry != lastCountry) {
      row.classList.add("reportpage");
      lastCountry = thisCountry;
    }
  })
}

window.onload = addReportPages;

</script>
```

**CSS** - includes new "reportpage" style

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen {
 th:nth-of-type(1),
 td:nth-of-type(1) {
 display: none;
 }
 .noPrint {}

 .titles {
  display: none;
 }
 .footer,.municipality,.certify,.numbers,.chief,.positions,.rev {
 display: none;
 }
 }
@media print {
  .noPrint {
    display: none;
  }
  .title {}
  .footer {}
  }
  
  .reportpage {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  

@page{
    size: auto;
    margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;  
}
body  
{ 
    margin: 0px;  
}


</style>
```

**HTML** - I've tidied this up a bit, to make it clearer to see what's happening:

```
<table  class="table" name="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="9">
         <div class="titles"><h3>This is Header title <br style="line-height: 20%;">
          <span class="header2"> SubHeader title</span>
         </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">
        <span class="municipality">Header</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="heads">
        <th class="heads">No</th>
        <th width ="5%" class="heads">ID Number</th>
        <th class="heads">Name</th>
        <th width ="8%" class="heads">Country</th>
        <th class="heads">Data total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="report-content">
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My entire HTML page that I used to test this:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Adding page breaks in a table</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function addReportPages() {
      let lastCountry = "";
      let table = document.getElementsByClassName("report-content")[0];
      let rows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
      rows.forEach(function(row){
        let thisCountry = row.cells[3].innerHTML;
        if (lastCountry == "") {
          lastCountry = thisCountry;
        } else if (thisCountry != lastCountry) {
          row.classList.add("reportpage");
          lastCountry = thisCountry;
        }
      })
    }

    window.onload = addReportPages;

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    @media screen {
     th:nth-of-type(1),
     td:nth-of-type(1) {
     display: none;
     }
     .noPrint {}

     .titles {
      display: none;
     }
     .footer,.municipality,.certify,.numbers,.chief,.positions,.rev {
     display: none;
     }
     }
    @media print {
      .noPrint {
        display: none;
      }
      .title {}
      .footer {}
      }
      
      .reportpage {
        page-break-before: always;
      }
      

    @page{
        size: auto;
        margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm;  
    }
    body  
    { 
        margin: 0px;  
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table  class="table" name="table" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="9">
             <div class="titles"><h3>This is Header title <br style="line-height: 20%;">
              <span class="header2"> SubHeader title</span>
             </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4" style="text-align: left;">
            <span class="municipality">Header</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="heads">
            <th class="heads">No</th>
            <th width ="5%" class="heads">ID Number</th>
            <th class="heads">Name</th>
            <th width ="8%" class="heads">Country</th>
            <th class="heads">Data total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="report-content">
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>United States</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>Germany</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>1235</td><td>Jason</td><td>China</td><td class="lenss"></td></tr>   
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222957/discussion-on-answer-by-atd-print-separate-page-based-on-data-table-html).